# Simple Virus Remover

Tags: c#, .net, patch, antivirus, virus

I am trying to create a simple virus remover. The algorithm I developed is meant to:

- inspect the original file and the infected file
- separate the virus from the infected file
- use same algorithm for repairing other files infected with the virus

I know this is possible, since this is the same way patches are created, but I am a little bit lost on how to go about with this.

Any help around??

Comment: If you have access to the orignal file, why not just copy it over the corrupted one ? Seems like a lot less work.

Comment: I think the point is to derive a general 'fix' that will work on any file infected with the same virus.

Comment: @driis: Yes, it's easier, but I don't want to do that. I want the program to be able to develop an algorithm for removing other files infected with the same virus

Comment: You have to be careful with false positives.

Comment: Writing an antivirus application that patches a file in place is pretty tricky business, and probably best left to the pros. The risk here doesn't seem to be worth it.

Comment: The title contains a contradiction in just 3 words: "simple" and "virus remover"

Comment: quite funny... you are right, but I have also seen other topics like simple assembly emulators though. Guess it all lies with the mindset

Comment: Did you write any simple code for this?

Comment: Yes [Robosam](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Antivirus/Removal-Tools/Robosys-Security-Anti-Malware.shtml) but not open source at the moment though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to put more intelligence than simply do some pattern matching and remove the isolated virus code.

The viruses you are aiming at are [files infectors](http://www.virusbtn.com/resources/glossary/file_infector_virus.xml) which are rarely used in our days.
Most of the time their replication process is as follow:

1. They copy themselves at the beginning or at the end of the [PE files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
2. Locate the entry point of the PE files
3. Put a jump instruction to this location pointing at theirs code

Disinfecting a file is the most difficult part for any anti-virus. It relies on the quality of the virus code: if it's buggy, the host file will just be unrecoverable.

In any case, you are entering a world of machine instructions where disassemblers (IDA, PE Explorer ...), and debuggers will be your dearest friends.

Comment: Well, this is a very useful answer. Thanks. I know about file infectors and also about the infection type that adds data to the alternate ntfs stream. Seems I have to do this myself as it appears I can only get advices here

Comment: Later figured out the disinfection process and it was just an opposite of the infection process. And yes it relies on the quality of the virus code but since an infected file is already useless, it doesn't really matter if we lose the file trying to repair it.. :-/

Comment: This is why disinfection is disappointing. It requires great amount of work for a random result... Combined with the fact that file infectors are no longer "in the wild" (http://www.wildlist.org/WildList/201101.htm) for quiet a while, it is a lost art.

Answer (score 0):

Do a difference of the two files, the basic idea would be to compare the original and infected files character by character until and saving discrepancies to some data structure. Then in the future you could look for the "virus" which would hypothetically be a collection of the differences, in other files and remove the "virus".

The only problem with this is that there will probably be discrepancies between the two files which have nothing to do with the "virus", e.g. the infected file was modified in some way different from the original, which has nothing to do with the virus.

EDIT***
Checking other files for the virus would not be too hard, but I am running under the assumption that you are dealing with some plain text form of file, for binary propitiatory files, I do not think you would be able to remove the "virus".

Comment: You have basically judged your solution as incorrect :-O

Comment: I was trying to say it depends on what type of file you are checking. Any algorithm which tries to remove a virus from a file is going to have a problem with compiled files.

Comment: Not if the virus we are removing is compiled too. Just think of a patch system and how it works. Or better think of a how a virus infects an already compiled program.

Comment: @Opatachibueze if it was easy as you make it sound then it already would be done.  I would argue that your solution might work for a while until the "bad guys" start make their virus do random things and have random signatures.  Oh wait they already do that...  Honestly the fact you are asking how to do this concerns me, the fact you want to do this in C# ( its good for a great deal of things ) but trusting it to scan and modify my system files..no thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your direct answer. I just love keeping a positive mindset about what I know is possible :) ,but you will be mistaken if you think I was creating a generic solution for patching all types of infection. It's just more like an experiment, but from my research, the subject of patching seems to be approached in many different manners. For now though, I'll be suspending the project till I acquire more knowledge about file manipulations